# Get return value from php to ajax

Tags: php, ajax, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am using `SweetAlert` for confirmation and I am having trouble getting the return data from my php to ajax

Here's what I am doing

my backend php

```
//Add A voucher
public function AddVoucher ($voucher_name, $quantity, $discount) 
{
    try
    {
            $stmt2 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM vouchers WHERE voucher_name=:voucher_name");
            $stmt2->bindParam(":voucher_name", $voucher_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt2->execute();
            $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if($stmt2->rowCount())
            {
                return "Failed";
            }
            else
            {
            $discount /= 100;
            //name doesn't exist so proceed to registration
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO vouchers (voucher_name,quantity,discount) 
            VALUES(:voucher_name, :quantity, :discount)");
            $stmt->bindParam(":voucher_name", $voucher_name,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":quantity", $quantity,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam(":discount", $discount,PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->execute();
    
            return $stmt;
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

my model php

```
<?php
require_once '../database/database.php';

$voucher_name = $_POST['voucher_name'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$discount = $_POST['discount'];

$result =  $user->AddVoucher($voucher_name,$quantity,$discount);

if($result == "Failed"):
    return false;
else:
    return true;
endif

?>
```

and now my frontend where my ajax exists

```
function SwalConfirm()
{
  
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You will an a voucher . Do you wish to proceed",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Proceed',
        cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn bg-gradient-primary w-30',
        cancelButtonClass: 'btn bg-gradient-secondary w-30',
        buttonsStyling: false,
        preConfirm: function()
        {
            return new Promise(function(resolve){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '../model/voucher_add.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:
                    {
                        voucher_name: $('#a_voucher_name').val(),
                        quantity: $('#a_quantity').val(),
                        discount: $('#a_discount').val()
                        
                    },
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                      if(!data)
                      {
                        Swal.fire('Opps!', 'Voucher Name Already Exists. Please Edit the current voucher instead','warning').then(function(){
                          location.reload();
                        });
                      }
                      else
                      {
                        Swal.fire('Success!', 'You have successfully added a voucher.','success').then(function(){
                            location.reload();
                        });
                      }
                    }
                })
                // .done(function(response)
                // {
                      // Swal.fire('Opps!', 'Voucher Name Already Exists. Please Edit the current voucher instead','warning').then(function(){
                      //     location.reload();
                      // });
                // })
                .fail(function(){
                    Swal.fire('Oppss!', 'There was something wrong declining this request.','success')
                })
            });
        }
  });
}
```

What I am trying to do here is that if the current voucher already exists then don't proceed and show an error using `sweetalert` instead of successful message

Comment: using `return` wont do anything, you need to echo 1 or 0, or respond with json and set the ajax call to handle it with `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: also be aware, `echo $ex->getMessage();` would cause it to break or look like true, the function should not catch then echo and return null, instead it should always return true or false, or an array of the new voucher or an empty array. You can catch the thrown exception when you call it.

Comment: np, don't know, I can't see any issue with your question

Comment: Can you write down your answer . It was actually solved now by just `echo '0'; ` for failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might encounter like this problem the solution for this is just this

```
if($stmt2->rowCount())
{
    echo "0";
}
```

then catch it to you ajax like this

```
if(data == 0)
{
    Swal.fire('Opps!', 'Voucher Name Already Exists. Please Edit the current voucher instead','warning').then(function(){
        location.reload();
     });
}
```

just something like that . But also follow what lawrence said regarding on catching the null

Answer (score 0):

**Model php:**

```
<?php

require_once '../database/database.php';

$voucher_name = $_POST['voucher_name'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$discount = $_POST['discount'];

$result =  $user->AddVoucher($voucher_name,$quantity,$discount);

if($result == "Failed"):
    return json_encode(false);
else:
    return json_encode(true);
endif

?>
```

It will return json_encoded result to ajax